# Error while deploying an EJB in JBOSS-Failed to load component class

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, jboss6.x

I am using Jboss-6.1.0. I am trying to create an EJB to print Hello world. I have three classess.
1.

```
    package remoteif;

    import java.rmi.*;
    import javax.ejb.*;
    public interface HelloWorld extends EJBObject{
        public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
    }
```

2.

```
    package homeif;

    import remoteif.HelloWorld;

    import javax.ejb.CreateException;
    import javax.ejb.EJBHome;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;


    public interface HelloWorldHome extends EJBHome {
        public HelloWorld create() throws
                CreateException, RemoteException;

    }
```

and
3.
        package beanimpl;

```
    import remoteif.HelloWorld;

    import javax.ejb.*;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;


    public class HelloWorldBean implements SessionBean {
        // Methods of Remote interface
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello, world !";
        }
        // Methods of Home interface
        public void ejbCreate() {}

        protected SessionContext ctx;
        public void setSessionContext(SessionContext ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
```

I am using two xml files ejb-jat.xml &jonas-ejb-jar.xml inside the META-INF directory. I have created jar file of this application (includes the class files and the xml files) and ear file that includes this jar file and the application.xml file. I have copied it in the JBOSS server. But when I am starting the server ,I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///data/EJB/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/wsdl/deploy/EjbSample.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///data/EJB/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/wsdl/deploy/EjbSample.ear/ejbDemo.jar/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load component class: HelloWorldBean from loader: BaseClassLoader@192c07a{vfs:///data/EJB/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/wsdl/deploy/EjbSample.ear}
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSEJBAdapterDeployer$WebServiceDeclarationAdapter.getComponentClass(WSEJBAdapterDeployer.java:232) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSEJBAdapterDeployer$WebServiceDeclarationAdapter.getAnnotation(WSEJBAdapterDeployer.java:214) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.util.ASHelper.isWebServiceBean(ASHelper.java:239) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.util.ASHelper.getJaxwsEjbs(ASHelper.java:222) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSTypeDeployer.isJaxwsEjbDeployment(WSTypeDeployer.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSTypeDeployer.internalDeploy(WSTypeDeployer.java:73) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 44 more

08:47:08,518 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
08:47:08,667 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
08:47:08,696 INFO  [service] Removing bootstrap log handlers
08:47:08,791 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile:: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///data/EJB/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/wsdl/deploy/EjbSample.ear" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load component class: HelloWorldBean from loader: BaseClassLoader@192c07a{vfs:///data/EJB/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/wsdl/deploy/EjbSample.ear}

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
```

What should I do to clear this error?